# Getting the price of Priority Mail Express in USPS shipping

Tags: fedex, usps

I required to get the rate for standard post,priority mail as well as priority express mail.Using below code i am getting the price rates for priority mail and standard post but not for priority express mail.

When in service column i write the priority express mail then there was an error as given below(Priority mail express)

"The requested Mail Service is not available for the specified request attributes."

Code i am using is this:

```php
{ 
    $url = "http://Production.ShippingAPIs.com/ShippingAPI.dll";
            $ch = curl_init();
            // set the target url
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            // parameters to post
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $data = "API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request USERID=\"$userName\"><Package ID=\"1ST\"><Service>All</Service><ZipOrigination>$orig_zip</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>$dest_zip</ZipDestination><Pounds>$weight</Pounds><Ounces>0</Ounces><Container/><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>FALSE</Machinable></Package>
            </RateV4Request>";
            
            // send the POST values to USPS
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
            $result=curl_exec ($ch);
            $data = strstr($result, '<?');
             //echo '<!-- '. $data. ' -->'; // Uncomment to show XML in comments
            $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
            xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $data, $vals, $index);
            xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
            $params = array();
            $level = array();
            foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
            if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'open') {
            if (array_key_exists('attributes',$xml_elem)) {
            list($level[$xml_elem['level']],$extra) = array_values($xml_elem['attributes']);
            } else {
            $level[$xml_elem['level']] = $xml_elem['tag'];
            }
            }
            if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'complete') {
            $start_level = 1;
            $php_stmt = '$params';
            while($start_level < $xml_elem['level']) {
            $php_stmt .= '[$level['.$start_level.']]';
            $start_level++;
            }
            $php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
            eval($php_stmt);
            }
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            //print_r($data);exit;
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($params); echo'</pre>'; // Uncomment to see the full array
            //echo $params['RATEV4RESPONSE']['1ST'][$servicecode]['RATE'];exit;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Priority Mail Express is not available for all types of shipments and it might be restricted in this case. Given that your request works for other mailclasses, there's a high likelihood that this is a shipping, not technical issue. It would help if you can share the specific parameters that you're sending.

If you want to play around with USPS shipping rates you can retrieve shipping rates for free with an easy UI or API at https://goshippo.com.

Comment: Thanks for the replyusername is 282CYBER5970

Comment: origin zipcode: 20505,destination zipcode: 01010, weight: 12lbs

Comment: What are the package dimensions and weight? Also, why do you set MACHINABLE to false? Most packages and envelopes are machinable.

Comment: ok i will make machinable true and i have not taken the input of package dimensions is it must to give dimensions also?

Comment: the package dimensions are not required, but weight is.

Comment: weight will be 12 pounds as an example

Comment: as it will vary according to the order.

Comment: Can you log the actual api request and response and post it here? Sorry but it's hard to debug only with the code above.

Comment: Request Parameters<code>API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request USERID='737STOUG2610'><Package ID=\"1ST\"><Service>All</Service><ZipOrigination>20505</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>67402</ZipDestination><Pounds>70</Pounds><Ounces>0</Ounces><Container>Variable</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>TRUE</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request></code>

Comment: Thanks for you support sir. I got the issue. The problem was with its origin zip code. May be express mail service is not available with this zip code (20505). Now it is working fine.  Thank You :)